# How to remove firebase observer?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tableView and refreshControl. I want that tableView's data reload only when I pull-to-refresh. I've made the function that reload data, but it works always.

Data reload after pull-to-refresh, but also observe update tableView.
How to remove it?
I want to make observe, reload data and remove observe (remove connection).

```
func reloadTable() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    postData.removeAll()

    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    databaseHandle = ref.child("doctors").child(userID!).observe(.childAdded) { 
        (snapshot) in
        if let actualPost = snapshot.value as? String {
            self.postData.append(actualPost)
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // I tried this:
    ref.removeAllObservers()

    // And this as well:
    ref.removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
let current = ref.child("doctors").child(userID!) 
 current.observe ///
current.removeAllObservers()
```

if you need to removeObservers you need to go deep as you add childs , as `removeAllObservers` for parents doesn't remove them for childs